# how to stop incoming SMTP .EML attack on an Azure Windows VM

Tags: windows, security, email, smtp

This morning 1:53am, my Azure VM began receiving unexpected .EML files in  C:\inetpub\mailroot\Queue.
By about 6am when I first logged on, it had received over 36000 files.
As a workaround, I stopped Services > SMTP.

How do I prevent this?
I'm working on a web app that will be sending and receiving SMTP.
I just started using SendGrid to send a few days ago, and am using just IIS to receive into: C:\inetpub\mailroot\Queue\

BELOW ARE THE FIRST AND LAST OF THE .EML FILES, AS A SAMPLE..........

FIRST .EML FILE.......................................

```
Received: from <MY PUBLIC IP> by prayshep with Microsoft SMTPSVC(8.5.9600.16384);
     Mon, 28 Dec 2015 01:53:49 -0800
Received: from XXXXXXXXXXXX  by ; Mon, 28 Dec 2015 12:46:42 +0300
Message-ID: <WPWTCYHGVOKQGPNWMSWDVVAN@yam.com>
From: "¡¹¤W¤dºØ¤é¥»¶i¤f±¡½ì¥Î«~¡¹Darren" <oddbjsh@hotmail.com>
Reply-To: "¡¹½ì¥Î«~ºë«~«Î¡¹Darren" <oddbjsh@hotmail.com>
To: q-kids@yahoo.com.tw
Subject: ¢e©Ê·P¨k¤º¿Ç¢eDarren
Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2015 06:52:42 -0300
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook Express 6.00.2462.0000
MIME-Version: 2.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="--44460359181169204938"
X-Priority: 3
X-MSMail-Priority: Normal
Return-Path: oddbjsh@hotmail.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 28 Dec 2015 09:53:50.0113 (UTC) FILETIME=[A70D0910:01D14155]

----44460359181169204938
Content-Type: text/html;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dbig5">
<title></title>
<style>
<!--
 p.MsoNormal
    {mso-style-parent:"";
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    margin-left:0cm; margin-right:0cm; margin-top:0cm}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table border=3D"0" width=3D"615" id=3D"table1">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9=
; font-weight: 700">
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none"><font color=3D"#008000">=B6i=A4f=A6=
=A8=A4H=B1=A1=BD=EC=A5=CE=AB~</font></span></a></span></p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b>
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9=
">
        <font color=3D"#FF0000">=B2=A2=AC=FC=BA=CE=A6=E7=A5=F4=BF=EF</font></spa=
n><font color=3D"#FF0000"><span style=3D"text-decoration: none"><span lang=
=3D"EN-US">3</span><span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9">=A5=
=F3</span><span lang=3D"EN-US">699</span></span></font><span style=3D"text=
-decoration: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9"><font color=3D"#FF=
0000">=A4=B8</font></span></a><font color=3D"#FF0000">
        </font></b></p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b><span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=
=E9">
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none"><font color=3D"#FF00FF">=A4=F5=BB=B6=
=A9=CA=B7P=AAA=B9=A2</font></span></a></span><font color=3D"#FF00FF">
        </font></b></p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9=
; font-weight: 700">
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none"><font color=3D"#00FFFF">=B1=A1=BD=EC=
=A5=CE=AB~=AC=C9=AA=BA=A4k=A4=FD=B6}=BDc=A4=E5</font></span></a></span></p=
>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b>
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none" lang=3D"EN-US"><font color=3D"#000=
000">
        AV</font></span><font color=3D"#000000"><span style=3D"text-decoration: =
none"><span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9">=A4k=C0u=AB=F6=BC=
=AF=B4=CE</span>
        <span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9">=A6W=BE=B9</span> </=
span></font>
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9=
">
        <font color=3D"#000000">=B5L=BDu=B8=F5=B3J</font></span></a></b></p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b>
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9=
">
        <font color=3D"#99CC00">=B0=AA=BC=E9</font></span><span style=3D"text-de=
coration: none"><font color=3D"#99CC00"><span lang=3D"EN-US">G</span><span=
 style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9">=C2I=B1M=B0=CF</span>
        <span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9">=B6W=A9=CA=B7P=AC=FC=
=BBL=B5=B7=C4=FB=A4=CE=BA=F4=C4=FB</span> </font></span></a></b>
        </p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b>
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9=
">
        <font color=3D"#FF66FF">=B7R=AA=B1=A8=A4=A6=E2=A7=EA=BAt</font></span><f=
ont color=3D"#FF66FF"><span style=3D"text-decoration: none">
        <span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9">=B9q=B0=CA=A6=DB=BC=A2=
=BE=B9</span>
        <span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9">=B0=AA=BC=E9=AA=BA=AF=
=B5=B1K</span><span lang=3D"EN-US">-</span></span></font><span style=3D"te=
xt-decoration: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9"><font color=3D"#=
FF66FF">=AB=C2=A6=D3=ACX</font></span></a></b></p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b>
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9=
">
        <font color=3D"#000000">=A5=FE=C0]=B6W=BC=F6=BD=E6=B0=D3=AB~</font></spa=
n><font color=3D"#FF0000"><span lang=3D"EN-US" style=3D"text-decoration: n=
one"><font size=3D"4">24</font></span></font><span style=3D"text-decoratio=
n: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9"><font color=3D"#000000">=B7Q=
=AE=C9=A7=D6=B3t=B0e=B9F</font></span></a></b></p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b><span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=
=E9">=B5L=AAk=B3s=B5=B2=BD=D0=BD=C6=BBs=BA=F4=A7}=A1=F7</span><span lang=3D=
"EN-US">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <font size=3D"4">http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3</font></a></span></b></p>
        <p>=A1@</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>


----44460359181169204938--
```

LAST.EML FILE........................................................

```
Received: from <MY PUBLIC IP> by prayshep with Microsoft SMTPSVC(8.5.9600.16384);
     Mon, 28 Dec 2015 05:19:41 -0800
Received: from 230.88.183.252 by ; Mon, 28 Dec 2015 09:16:36 -0400
Message-ID: <LRBOOITCSSBMFNYHLKZIFNL@pchome.com.tw>
From: "¡¹¶i¤f¦¨¤H±¡½ì¥Î«~¡¹Charity" <gocmfuiepnvn@pchome.com.tw>
Reply-To: "¡¹¼Ö¦h±¡½ì¥Î«~¡¹Charity" <ffqbqnljzp@pchome.com.tw>
To: freewilldesigner@yahoo.com.tw
Subject: ¢e­¸¾÷ªM¨t¦C¢eCharity
Date: Mon, 28 Dec 2015 07:16:36 -0600
X-Mailer:   
MIME-Version: 2.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="--=====754321844504=_"
X-Priority: 3
X-MSMail-Priority: Normal
Return-Path: umlxtoita@pchome.com.tw
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 28 Dec 2015 13:19:41.0886 (UTC) FILETIME=[694805E0:01D14172]

----=====754321844504=_
Content-Type: text/html;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv=3D"Content-Type" content=3D"text/html; charset=3Dbig5">
<title></title>
<style>
<!--
 p.MsoNormal
    {mso-style-parent:"";
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:12.0pt;
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    margin-left:0cm; margin-right:0cm; margin-top:0cm}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table border=3D"0" width=3D"615" id=3D"table1">
    <tr>
        <td>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9=
; font-weight: 700">
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none"><font color=3D"#008000">=B6i=A4f=A6=
=A8=A4H=B1=A1=BD=EC=A5=CE=AB~</font></span></a></span></p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b>
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9=
">
        <font color=3D"#FF0000">=B2=A2=AC=FC=BA=CE=A6=E7=A5=F4=BF=EF</font></spa=
n><font color=3D"#FF0000"><span style=3D"text-decoration: none"><span lang=
=3D"EN-US">3</span><span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9">=A5=
=F3</span><span lang=3D"EN-US">699</span></span></font><span style=3D"text=
-decoration: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9"><font color=3D"#FF=
0000">=A4=B8</font></span></a><font color=3D"#FF0000">
        </font></b></p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b><span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=
=E9">
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none"><font color=3D"#FF00FF">=A4=F5=BB=B6=
=A9=CA=B7P=AAA=B9=A2</font></span></a></span><font color=3D"#FF00FF">
        </font></b></p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9=
; font-weight: 700">
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none"><font color=3D"#00FFFF">=B1=A1=BD=EC=
=A5=CE=AB~=AC=C9=AA=BA=A4k=A4=FD=B6}=BDc=A4=E5</font></span></a></span></p=
>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b>
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none" lang=3D"EN-US"><font color=3D"#000=
000">
        AV</font></span><font color=3D"#000000"><span style=3D"text-decoration: =
none"><span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9">=A4k=C0u=AB=F6=BC=
=AF=B4=CE</span>
        <span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9">=A6W=BE=B9</span> </=
span></font>
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9=
">
        <font color=3D"#000000">=B5L=BDu=B8=F5=B3J</font></span></a></b></p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b>
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9=
">
        <font color=3D"#99CC00">=B0=AA=BC=E9</font></span><span style=3D"text-de=
coration: none"><font color=3D"#99CC00"><span lang=3D"EN-US">G</span><span=
 style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9">=C2I=B1M=B0=CF</span>
        <span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9">=B6W=A9=CA=B7P=AC=FC=
=BBL=B5=B7=C4=FB=A4=CE=BA=F4=C4=FB</span> </font></span></a></b>
        </p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b>
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9=
">
        <font color=3D"#FF66FF">=B7R=AA=B1=A8=A4=A6=E2=A7=EA=BAt</font></span><f=
ont color=3D"#FF66FF"><span style=3D"text-decoration: none">
        <span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9">=B9q=B0=CA=A6=DB=BC=A2=
=BE=B9</span>
        <span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9">=B0=AA=BC=E9=AA=BA=AF=
=B5=B1K</span><span lang=3D"EN-US">-</span></span></font><span style=3D"te=
xt-decoration: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9"><font color=3D"#=
FF66FF">=AB=C2=A6=D3=ACX</font></span></a></b></p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b>
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <span style=3D"text-decoration: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9=
">
        <font color=3D"#000000">=A5=FE=C0]=B6W=BC=F6=BD=E6=B0=D3=AB~</font></spa=
n><font color=3D"#FF0000"><span lang=3D"EN-US" style=3D"text-decoration: n=
one"><font size=3D"4">24</font></span></font><span style=3D"text-decoratio=
n: none; font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=E9"><font color=3D"#000000">=B7Q=
=AE=C9=A7=D6=B3t=B0e=B9F</font></span></a></b></p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal">=A1@</p>
        <p class=3D"MsoNormal"><b><span style=3D"font-family: =B7s=B2=D3=A9=FA=C5=
=E9">=B5L=AAk=B3s=B5=B2=BD=D0=BD=C6=BBs=BA=F4=A7}=A1=F7</span><span lang=3D=
"EN-US">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a target=3D"_blank" href=3D"http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3">
        <font size=3D"4">http://bit.ly/1QSvkx3</font></a></span></b></p>
        <p>=A1@</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>


----=====754321844504=_--
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting an "`.eml` file attack". You're getting a ton of spam email sent to you, which is quite natural, and IIS stores the email in RFC822 compliant files that end in `.eml`.

If you want to stop the `.eml` files from piling up, you need to block the spammer. To do that, you need to perform any one of about nine million different ways to discourage and block spam, many of which won't be doable when you're only using IIS for SMTP. Consider determining if there are common IP addresses that the spam is coming from and blocking them, or blocking entire networks that seem to be problematic. This would be done with either Windows Firewall, or the firewall that is in front of the IIS server.

The better solution would be to choose an SMTP server that has more features and functionality to allow for blocking spam.

Comment: You may also decide to only accept mail from the IPs of app users, rather than the general internet.

Comment: Jim B:  I must accept from general Internet.

Comment: Wesley: What is a good, preferably free, SMTP server?  I am using SendGrid for outgoing email send.